Projection operator for pressure in relativistic hydrodynamic
(I am a new contributer to this forum and hope that this comment made after the closing of the question can serve as an explainer. I am a 65 year young citizen scientist and use the studying of gravitation and astrophysics as a way to delay my cognitive degeneration. These subject area is completely new to me and find it exciting and captivating. But at this age, I find it possible to grasp new concept idea but hard to follow the minute details of the arithmetic in equation derivation. For sure, i will ask questions again and stick within the guidelines in future.)
The projection operator in relativistic hydrodynamic has the form :
$P^{\alpha}_{\beta} =
  \delta^{\alpha}_{\beta}
  +u^{\alpha}u_{\beta}/c^2$
where $u^{\alpha}/c = \gamma(1,v/c,0,0)$ assuming velocity in only one spatial direction.
It has an identity:
$P^{\alpha}_{\alpha} = 3$
Excuse me, summing $P^{\alpha}_{\alpha}$ for $\alpha$ from 0 to 3, I just get 0, with signature (-1,1,1,1). Am I missing something here?

Where is the problem?
$$\sum_{\alpha=0}^3 (\delta^\alpha_\alpha + u^\alpha u_\alpha/c^2)= \left(\sum_{\alpha=0}^3 1\right) - \frac{c^2}{c^2}=
 4 -1 = 3$$
